# Awesomium WebCore is not running

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, awesomium

Am using Awesomium.Core and creating a windows form application in which am using awesomium dll. The problem am getting is that am initializing the WebCore (Awesomium.Core.WebCore)

```
// Set some initialization settings.
        WebConfig webConfig = new WebConfig()
        {
            HomeURL = new Uri("about:blank"),
            LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose
        };

        // Lazy initialization of the core.
        WebCore.Initialize(webConfig);
```

But when am calling WebCore.IsRunning it always return me false... I have changed the webConfig too

```
if (!WebCore.IsRunning)
                WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig() { LogLevel = LogLevel.Normal });
```

But still WebCore is not running. Please help me out in this problem, will be gratefull to you. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a view after initialising the WebCore? Lazy initialisation means that the WebCore will start when the first view is created.

Comment: yes am creating it in main Program.cs class and checking it before creating my view. After some research i got the point that WebCore will be in running mode when my view is completely created. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There is no point in checking it before you create the view, as it doesn't run until a view is created. Remember to mark questions as answered if you feel they have been.

Comment: yeah i got this point later as i am using it first time and i don't have much knowledge about awesomium webCore. By the way thanks for the answer.